# For field extension $M/L/K$ with $M/K$ normal, if $\sigma\in\mathrm{Aut}(M/K)$ implies $\sigma(L)\subset M^{\mathrm{Aut}(M/L)}$, must $L/K$ be normal?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, normal-extension

Let $M/K$ be a **normal** extension, $L$ be an intermediate field. Suppose that for every $\sigma\in\mathrm{Aut}(M/K)$, $\sigma(L)\subset M^{\mathrm{Aut}(M/L)}$ ($M^{\mathrm{Aut}(M/L)}$ is the subfield of $M$ fixed by $\mathrm{Aut}(M/L)$). Is it true that for every $\sigma\in\mathrm{Aut}(M/K)$, $\sigma(L)\subset L$?

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803181/if-l-k-normal-and-h-operatornameautl-k-then-l-lh-is-separable-and) says that $M^{\mathrm{Aut}(M/L)}$ is a purely inseparable extension of $L$, but what can happen if $M^{\mathrm{Aut}(M/L)}$ is strictly larger than $L$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $K = \Bbb{F}_p( x^p+y^p,x^py^p),L =\Bbb{F}_p(x^p,y), M=\Bbb{F}_p(x,y)$

Comment: You really saved my day, thanks a lot!