# Proof of that integral closure of finitely generated domain $R$ over field is finitely generated $R$-module (Eisenbud, Corollary 13.13, Emmy Noether)

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am reading the Eisenbud, Commutative Algebra, Corollary 13.13 ( Emmy Noether ) and stuck at some statement.

First, I propose a relavant question.

**Q.** Let $R:=k[x_1 , \dots , x_d]$ with $\operatorname{char}(k)=p >0$ so that its fraction field is $K=K(R) = k(x_1, \dots ,x_d)$. Let $L'/K$ be a finite purely inseparable extension. Then there exists a power $q$ of $p$ such that $L'$ is obtained from $K$ by adjoining finitely many $q$-th roots of elements $f_i \in K$ ( $\because$ Since $L'/K$ is finite dimensional purely inseparable extension, $L'=K(u_1, \dots , u_m)$, where $u_1 , \dots , u_m$ are purely inseparable element over $K$ ; i.e., $u_1^{p^{n_1}}, \dots , u_m^{p^{n_m}} \in K=k(x_1, \dots ,x_d)$ for some $n_1, \dots , n_m \ge 0$. Let $n:=n_1 + \cdots + n_m$. Then $u_1^{p^n} , \dots , u_m^{p^n} \in K$ ).

Let $L'':=k'(x_1^{1/q} , \dots , x_d^{1/q})$ where $k'$ is the finite extension of $k$ obtained by adjoining all $q$-th roots of all coefficients of the $f_i$. Note that $L' \subseteq L''$ ( and finite extension? )

**Then, the integral closure $\bar{R}^{L''}$ of $R$ in $L''$ is $T:=k'[x_1^{1/q},\dots,x_d^{1/q}]$ and $T$ is finite over $R$?**

This question originates from following proof of Eisenbud's book ( corollary 13.13 ).

**Corollary 13.13** (Emmy Noether). Let $R$ be an affine domain over a field $k$ ( ; i.e., finitely generated domain over $k$ ). Set $K=K(R)$ and let $L$ be a finite extension field of $K$. If $T$ is the integral closure of $R$ in $L$, then $T$ is a finitely generated $R$-module ; in particular, $T$ is again an affine domain.

*Proof.* By Noether normalization, $R$ is a finite module over a polynomial ring $k[x_1, \dots, x_d] \subset R$, and it suffices to prove the corollary after replacing $R$ by this subring ( $\because$  The integral closure $T$ of $R$ in $L$ is also the integral closure of $k[x_1, \dots,x_d]$ in $L$, and if $T$ is finite over $k[x_1, \dots x_d]$ it is also finite over $R$.). Further, since a submodule of a finitely generated module is finitely generated, it suffices to prove the corollary after making a finite extension of $L$, and thus we may replace $L$ by its normal closure and assume that $L/K$ is a normal extension in the sense of Galois theory.

Let $L'$ be the fixed field of the Galois group of $L$ over $K$, so that $L/L'$ is Galois and $L'/K$ is purely inseparable ( C.f. [If $L/K$ normal and $H = \operatorname{Aut}(L/K)$, then $L/L^H$ is separable and $L^H/K$ is purely inseparable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803181/if-l-k-normal-and-h-operatornameautl-k-then-l-lh-is-separable-and) ). We shall first show that the integral closure $R'$ of $R$ in $L'$ is a finitely generated $R$-module.

If $L'=K$ this is trivial, so we suppose that $L' \neq K$. Let $p$ be the characteristic of $L$, which is necessarily nonzero since $L'/K$ is purely inseparable.

For some power $q$ of $p$, the field $L'$ is generated by finitely many $q$-th roots of elements $f_i \in K = k(x_1 ,\dots x_d)$ ( $\because$ Since $L'/K$ is finite dimensional purely inseparable extension, $L'=K(u_1, \dots , u_m)$, where $u_1 , \dots , u_m$ are purely inseparable element over $K$ ; i.e., $u_1^{p^{n_1}}, \dots , u_m^{p^{n_m}} \in K=k(x_1, \dots ,x_d)$ for some $n_1, \dots , n_m \ge 0$. Let $n:=n_1 + \cdots + n_m$. Then $u_1^{p^n} , \dots , u_m^{p^n} \in K$ ). Extending $L'$ further by adjoining $q$-th roots of their coefficients, we may assume that
$$ L' =k'(x_1^{1/q},\dots ,x_d^{1/q})$$
where $k'$ is obtained from $k$ by adjoining the $q$-th roots of the coefficients ( $\because$ Note that $k'(x_1^{1/q},\dots ,x_d^{1/q})$ is really extension of $L'$ (?). Check this for simplest case that $R=k[x]$ (so that $K=k(x)$) and $L'= K(f^{1/q})$, where $f=\frac{a_mx^m + \cdots + a_0}{b_nx^n + \cdots + b_0} \in K$ ; using the Freshman's dream ( We have $\operatorname{char}L =p$) ). **The integral closure of $R$ in $L'$ is $T=k'[x_1^{1/q} , \dots, x_d^{1/q}]$, since this ring is integrally closed, has quotient field $L'$, and is finite over $R$.** Since $R' \subset T$, this shows that $R'$ is finite over $R$.

In Proposition 13.14 we shall see that the integral closure of the normal ring $R'$ in the Galois extension $L$ of $L'$ is finitely generated over $R'$. Since $R'$ is itself finitely generated over $R$, this completes the proof.

> Proposition 13.14. Suppose that $R$ is a Noetherian normal domain with quotient field $K$. If $L$ is a finite separable extension of $K$, then the integral closure of $R$ in $L$ is a finitely generated $R$-module.

**QED.**

Why the bold statement is true?

**Q.** Why the integral closure of $R=k[x_1, \dots, x_d]$ in $L'$ is $T=k'[x_1^{1/q} , \dots, x_d^{1/q}]$ and why $T$ is finite over $R$ ?

Can anyone help?

Comment: The question would be easier to answer (and more people are likely you read it) if you extract the relevant context. Your question is not about the full proof, only about the statement that a certain integral closure is given by a certain ring. Please omit all the rest, give the definitions only of the remaining symbols, and I bet you will get some help.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I follow your advice and ask a question that focuses on the main points and inserted it in the first paragraph in my original question. Perhaps, if you have time, can you help me? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken this should be rather simple.

Since $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$ are algebraically independent over $k$, they are also algebraically independent over $k'$ (this just a finite extension of $k$ and has nothing to do with the variables), and then also $x_1^{1/q},\dotsc,x_d^{1/q}$ are algebraically independent over $k'$. This means, actually, $T$ is a polynomial ring over $k'$ in $d$ variables, therefore factorial and hence integrally closed in $Q(T)$.

The elements of $k'$ are integral over $k$ and hence integral over $R$. The elements $x_1^{1/q},\dotsc,x_d^{1/q}$ are integral over $R$ as well (consider $T^q - x_i$). So we see that $T$ is a finitely generated $R$-algebra that is generated by integral elements. Hence, $T$ is finite and integral over $R$.

The integral closure $C$ of $R$ in $L''$ satisfies $T \subseteq C$, but since $T$ is integrally closed in $Q(T) = L''$, we must have $T=C$.

Comment: O.K. Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: I forgot the reason for the final statement ; Why $C\subseteq T$? Since $R \subseteq T \Rightarrow C:=\overline{R}^{L''} \subseteq \overline{T}^{L''} = T$ ? I'm not sure if $R\subseteq T$.